# How does 'em' css unit work for positioned elements?

Tags: html, css

Below is the html code with nested `div` and a `p` as innermost element,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>How em unit works?</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p> Some text</p>           
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

if styled as,

```
body{
    font-size: 10px;  /* Default font size is 16 css pixels for body tag*/
}

body > div{
    font-size: 20px;

}

body > div > div{
    font-size: 50px;
}

p{
    font-size: 0.5em;   /*   25 css pixels  */
    width: 6em;         /* 6X50 css pixels  */
    height: 6em;        /* 6X50 css pixels  */  
    padding-right: 3em; /* 3X50 css pixels  */  
    margin-left: 3em;   /* 3X50 css pixels  */  
    background-color: red;
}
```

then, paragraph text, takes `font-size` as `0.5 x 50px`(0.5 times of nearest parent `font-size`).

My question,

```
body{
    font-size: 10px;  /* Default font size is 16 css pixels for body tag*/
}

body > div{
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;

}

body > div > div{
    font-size: 50px;
}

p{
    font-size: 0.5em;   
    width: 6em;         
    height: 6em;        
    padding-right: 3em; 
    margin-left: 3em;   
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
}
```

if `p` gets `position: absolute` and outer most `div` become `position: relative`, then, How does the `em` unit behavior change for `p` element?

Comment: It doesn't change. Positioning doesn't effect font size. Is there a specific issue you're running into? If so, can you replicate it for us? P.S. I think you meant `25px` where you have `15px` in your code example. FWIW I would start using `rem` instead of `em` if you don't need to support IE8. Easier to work with.

Comment: @hungerstar Correct. let me edit.

Comment: Use `rem` it's much easier to track relative sizes with

Comment: @Martin Do you mean, `rem` unit will catch root element `font-size` unlike `em` unit that catches immediate parent element computed `font-size`? So easy to determine the behavior using `rem` unit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does the em unit behavior change, if p is position: absolute?

It doesn't change at all.

The parent element is still the parent element.

Comment: I could not view the `font-size` in `p` using developer tools. It still shows `0.5em`. How do I see the `font-size`?

Comment: @overexchange check to view the *computed* values

Comment: So, unlike `%` css unit, `em` unit behavior does not change

Answer (score 1):

Position does not impact `em` sizing. So it will be the same no matter the position of the paragraph. 
I prefer `rem` over em though. `em` can get weird sometimes and if you are not keeping track of everything can make some stuff look wonky.

EDIT: I see two others beat me to answering this.